# Binary search tree with $n$ internal vertices

Tags: data-structures, combinatorics, trees, search-trees

How can we prove a binary search tree with $n$ internal vertices has height $h = \lceil \log(n+1) \rceil$?

Comment: I assume you mean to restrict the discussion to balanced binary search trees, since otherwise the claim is, in general, false.

Comment: A binary search tree is always balanced.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Not according to standard definitions of which I'm aware. Why would a binary search tree require balancing?

Comment: You're right. I meant "full", i.e. every node has two children. Perhaps the question is to show that the height is *at least* $\lceil \log (n+1) \rceil$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Still not sure; to me, "full" means that non-leaf nodes have two children. I can imagine trees that satisfy the requirements of "Binary Search Tree" and fail to satisfy the requirements of "Full"... in any event, I think I agree the intention must be for a lower bound (since the upper bound is pretty trivial).

Comment: This is a dump of an exercise problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See also [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/470/) for our homework policy, and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594) for a relevant discussion. You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/). If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?